# NameError: name 'model' is not defined in python code for isolated speech recognition

Tags: python-3.x, nameerror, hidden-markov-models

I downloaded the code from https://github.com/prakashpandey9/IsolatedSpeechRecognition

That code was compatible with Python 2 and I wrote it for Python 3.

But I m getting this error:

```
~/Desktop/IsolatedSpeechRecognition-master $ python Isolated_Speech_Recognition.py 
    List of spoken words: ['dog', 'human', 'god', 'eye', 'book', 'fast', 'apple', 'cat']
    {'book', 'human', 'fast', 'apple', 'god', 'cat', 'dog', 'eye'}
    Number of total files: 120
    Labels and label indices [6. 6. 6. 6. 6. 6. 6. 6. 6. 6. 6. 6. 6. 6. 6. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
     1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 4. 7. 7. 7.
     7. 7. 7. 7. 7. 7. 7. 7. 7. 7. 7. 7. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
     0. 0. 0. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3.
     3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]
    (120, 3841)
    Processed observation 0
    Processed observation 10
    Processed observation 20
    Processed observation 30
    Processed observation 40
    Processed observation 50
    Processed observation 60
    Processed observation 70
    Processed observation 80
    Processed observation 90
    Processed observation 100
    Processed observation 110
    (120, 7, 33)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Isolated_Speech_Recognition.py", line 269, in <module>
        _ = [model.train(X_train[y_train == y, :, :]) for m, y in zip(ms, ys)]
      File "Isolated_Speech_Recognition.py", line 269, in <listcomp>
        _ = [model.train(X_train[y_train == y, :, :]) for m, y in zip(ms, ys)]
    NameError: name 'model' is not defined
```

this is the code snippet where I m getting error:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(test_size=0.1, random_state=0)

for n,i in enumerate(all_obs):
    all_obs[n] /= all_obs[n].sum(axis=0)


for train_index, test_index in sss.split(all_obs, all_labels):
    X_train, X_test = all_obs[train_index, ...], all_obs[test_index, ...]
    y_train, y_test = all_labels[train_index], all_labels[test_index]
ys = set(all_labels)
ms = [gmmhmm(7) for y in ys]

_ = [model.train(X_train[y_train == y, :, :]) for m, y in zip(ms, ys)]
ps1 = [model.test(X_test) for m in ms]
res1 = np.vstack(ps1)
predicted_label1 = np.argmax(res1, axis=0)
dictionary = ['apple', 'banana', 'elephant', 'dog', 'frog', 'cat', 'jack', 'god', 'Intelligent', 'hello']
spoken_word = []
for i in predicted_label1:
    spoken_word.append(dictionary[i])
print(spoken_word)
missed = (predicted_label1 != y_test)
print('Test accuracy: %.2f percent' % (100 * (1 - np.mean(missed))))
```

I tried but not able to find why I am getting this error and how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You call `model.train()` without defining `model` as the error message indicates.

If the model you want to train in the list comprehension is `m` then it should be:

`[m.train(X_train[y_train == y, :, :]) for m, y in zip(ms, ys)]`

The following line needs the same change:

`[m.test(X_test) for m in ms]`